# Load image from local machine and render using react js

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to load an image from the local machine and then display it, the problem is that when I load the image, instead of giving me the absolute path of the file, it gives a fake path as shown below:

```
C:\fakepath\image0.jpg
```

The problem is that this path does not exist so it makes an error, how can I get the absolute path and then render the image when the image is uploaded?
This is the code that I have:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isImage: false,
      val: "",
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      mySrc: e.target.value,
      isImage: true,
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { isImage, val } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="file"
            id="imgInp"
            value={val}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <img id="myImg" src={val} alt="car image" />
        </form>
        {isImage ? (
          <img src={require(val)} />
        ) : (
          <p> Please select an image </p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is stored in `event.target.files[0]` not `event.target.value`, then you need to create an URL for that file using [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

So in your case should be

```js
mySrc: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
```